# Как использовать Numpy в Ursina Python при детектировании пересечений

Tags: python, numpy, ursina

В Ursina выполняю поиск пересечений. В цикле всё работает. Пытаюсь применить Numpy, чтобы избавиться от цикла, но Ursina ругается на массивы. Как можно использовать функционал Numpy, чтобы не применять цикл?

```
from ursina import *
import numpy as np
app = Ursina()
cube_1 = Entity(model='cube', collider='box')
cube_2 = Entity(model='cube', collider='box')
cube_3 = Entity(model='cube', collider='box')
lst = []
lst.append(cube_2)
lst.append(cube_3)

for m in range(2):
    if cube_1.intersects(lst[m]).hit:
        print('intersects 1')

arr = np.asarray(lst)
np.where(cube_1.intersects(arr).hit == True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуй, `numpy` вам здесь не поможет. Метод `intersect` ожидает на вход объект сцены, а не массив, поэтому цикл - наиболее естественный способ.

Если вы настаиваете на `numpy` и без циклов, то нужно *векторизовать* метод `intersect` (не тестировал!):

```
np.where(np.vectorize(lambda scene: cube_1.intersects(scene).hit)(arr))
```

`np.vectorize` превращает обычную функцию в векторную.

Так как у массивов `ndarray` нельзя брать атрибуты объектов, то обращение к атрибуту `hit` приходится оборачивать в `lambda`.

Я подозреваю, что `np.where` в таких условиях будет медленнее цикла.

Comment: При использовании print( np.where(np.vectorize(lambda scene: cube_1.intersects(scene).hit)(arr)) ) выводит такой результат: (array([0, 1], dtype=int64),)

Comment: значит, кубы с индексами 0 и 1 пересекаются с `cube_1`